# Download files from lwc (from Google drive) in zip

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have LWC where i showed files  from Google Drive.
I want to download it like zip.
I used Named Credentials with Auth Provider to connect GD. I found library JSZip and try to use it.
When we add new file to zip we need blob of this file. but i can not get it.
I read that [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221uzMwP1vTm8SwN5CNo9EFDd0TRCWuj9it%22%2C%22alt%22%3A%22media%22%7D) dives the blob....but how?

Also i try to fetch(webContentLink)...but what about access? Can i use named credentials on js?

```
async downloadFolder(event){
    console.log('1');
    const folder = event.detail;
    console.log('2');
    let zip = new JSZip();
    console.log('3');
    const folderContent = await getFolderContent({folderId: folder.id});
    console.log('4');
    const files = folderContent.files;

    
    files.forEach(async (file)=>{
        console.log(file.webContentLink);
        fetch(file.webContentLink)
        .then(response => response.blob()) 
        .then(blob => {
            zip.file(file.name, blob);
        })
    });
    console.log('5');

    zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'})
    .then((content)=>{
        saveAs(content,folder.name +'.zip')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error while generating the zip file:', error);
    });
    console.log('6');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add all the Google Drive URLs to CSP in Salesforce?

Comment: @Rahul Gawale  I add to CSP only this url: 'https://drive.google.com'

Comment: @RahulGawale what else needs to be added to CSP?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this is blocked by Google Drive and not Salesforce, You need to add your SF instance URL to Google Cloud's CSP policy from the admin console. Alternatively, You can suppress this error but there are some caveats with that. See that the *https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc* section from this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc

Comment: @RahulGawale i`m not sure, because  when i  insert any url (to img).... the error is repeated. Maybe there are another methods, without fetch()?

Answer (score 0):

it was realy easy!

so, to get blob files (that we need for create zip file) from Google Drive we need just add 'alt=media' in getFileContent endpoint.

```
public String getFileContent(String fileId){
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndpoint(baseEndpoint + 'files/' + fileId +'?alt=media&'+ generateOptionalParameters());
    System.debug('Endpoint: ' + request.getMethod() + '__' + request.getEndpoint());
    HttpResponse response = new http().send(request); 
    System.debug('Response ' + response.getBody());
    String body = response.getBody();
    return body;
}
```

We will get a strange array of characters. But we can encode this:

```
const fileContent = await getFileContent({ fileId: file.id });

const byteArray = new Uint8Array(fileContent.length);
for (let i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
     byteArray[i] = fileContent.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}

const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: file.mimeType });
zipFolder.file(file.name, blob);
```

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution, but the answer you posted is not that clear, can you please share the code where you added alt=media also share the getFileContent code. I will upvote once you do that. It will help others if you add more information.

Comment: @RahulGawale but i have one problem, I can not open files in downloaded zip

Comment: so is it not working?

Comment: no, unfortunately  it doesn`t work. More precisely: the zip is created, but the files in it do not open. Do you know what is problem?

Comment: No, that is why I asked.